# Unable to click radio button even after using explicit wait on selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to select 'Female' Radio Button in the webpage

```
import time
import selenium.common.exceptions
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Drivers\chrome\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://fs2.formsite.com/meherpavan/form2/index.html?1537702596407")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "RESULT_RadioButton-7_1")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",element)
#element.click()

#driver.find_element_by_id("RESULT_RadioButton-7_1").click()
print(driver.find_element_by_id("RESULT_RadioButton-7_0").is_selected())
print(driver.find_element_by_id("RESULT_RadioButton-7_1").is_selected())
```

**Error:**

```
C:\Users\kkumaraguru\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/kkumaraguru/PycharmProjects/SeleniumProject/RadioButtons.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kkumaraguru\PycharmProjects\SeleniumProject\RadioButtons.py", line 14, in <module>
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "RESULT_RadioButton-7_1")))
  File "C:\Users\kkumaraguru\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it times out waiting for an element with ID `RESULT_RadioButton-7_1` to be present on the page. I'd open the page yourself to make sure such element is present. You can do this using javascript in the browser's console: `document.getElementById("RESULT_RadioButton-7_1")`. If this doesn't work then try to debug through the code, and check what HTML Selenium is looking at to make sure is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `JS intervention`, Also make sure to **maximize** the windows size like below :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://fs2.formsite.com/meherpavan/form2/index.html?1537702596407")

#time.sleep(5)
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "RESULT_RadioButton-7_1")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: I'm not sure in it, but it seems like `RESULT_RadioButton-7_1` is a dynamic element.

Comment: @vitaliis: This is now 8 months old, you could try with CSS or xpath ? Did you try that?

Comment: I had a similar problem and found out that XPath and search by label would work more accurately. Even when I myself prefer using CSS selectors.

Comment: @vitaliis: I suggested him to use `execute_script`, locator I must have copied from the OP